# Find the element value and check if it's enabled or disabled --selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a radio kind button like enable/disable on the device webpage.After logging into the webpage,depending on the checked value,should know whether that it is enabled or disabled.

Below is the code for enable and disable

```
<li class="">
<input id="manage_site_en" type="radio" value="Enabled" name="manage_site_en"/>
<label for="manage_site_enabled">Enabled</label>
</li>
<li id="off" class="selected">
<input id="manage_site_en" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Disabled" name="manage_site_en"/>
<label for="manage_site_disabled">Disabled</label>
</li>
```

How to traverse and extract the value checked="checked" .Please help.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: You want to check enabled/disabled or checked/unchecked ? Try using xpath to get the appropriate value ..

Comment: Tried using xpath ,but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you have the `isSelected()` method to assist you with that.
An example:

```
boolean isChecked = driver.findElement(By.tagName("manage_site_en")).isSelected;
```